# Strange spelling of final m

Tags: spelling

In a 16th century Latin treatise published in Poland several occurences of the final m have the form of ꝫ (in Unicode U+A76B LATIN SMALL LETTER ET).
You can find more information about the work at https://github.com/jsbien/Zaborowski-index4djview. An illustration demonstrating that sonum and scilitet end with the same letter can be found in the preprint https://www.researchgate.net/publication/341930612 (available on request). Is there an explanation?
I will appreciate your comments.

Comment: See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribal_abbreviation#Marks_with_relative_meaning

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel, I don't see the relevance of this Wikipedia entry to my question.

Comment: The Wikipedia article says that the _et_ mark "after a, e, u vowels meant -m not us or ei, if after an o it meant -nem", but there's no citation for that (and it's explained in kind of a roundabout way).

Comment: @Draconis The whole text is, however, very closely based on the [Lexicon Abbreviaturarum](https://archive.org/details/LexiconAbbreviaturarum/page/n25/mode/2up) (German edition). The explanation there is slightly less confusing if you can read German, much more if not. I couldn't find the Italian original edition online.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel Thank you very much! I missed the relevant passage in the entry at first reading. I'm also not aware of the original edition of  Lexicon Abbreviaturarum online, but there is [an English edition](https://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/bitstream/handle/1808/1821/47cappelli.pdf) (and [the interactive one](https://www.adfontes.uzh.ch/en/ressourcen/abkuerzungen/cappelli-online) but without the preface).

Comment: @Draconis  Thank you very much.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Could write up the relevant bit into an answer? It doesn't have to be long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the introduction to Capelli's abbreviation dictionary](https://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/bitstream/handle/1808/1821/47cappelli.pdf) (section 4.281), as translated by Heimann and Kay:

> When the ꝫ-mark occurs at the end of a word and is preceded by the vowel *a*, *e*, or *u*, it generally does not stand for *-us* or *-et*, but rather for *m*. It is almost always written on the same line as the other letters in the word, for example: naꝫ = nam; o̅e̅ꝫ = omnem; h̅i̅tuꝫ = habitum.

(Section 4.28 in general is dedicated to this sign, and goes through various other meanings in other contexts, such as *-nem* with preceded by *o* or *-rum* when marked with an additional slash.)